# Apache2 Proxy Error:Error reading from remote server

Tags: java, server, proxy, apache2, nanohttpd

Environment:

- Apache2
- nanohttpd (web server (java))

The site itself is and has been working fine, I have added alot of entries to a database which the nanohttpd web server returns on some endpoints

I have figured out that is has todo with the length of the site being returned since when I move entries from one status to another, the one with alot of entries will always give me this error.

I already looked around a bit and think it may be a timeout issue but I have added timeouts to my virtual host and this problem still persists

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /foo

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at foo.foo.foo Port 443
```

My current VirtualHost file for this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/directory

            ServerName foo.foo.foo
            ServerAlias foo.foo.foo

            ProxyPass "/" "http://foo.com:8080/"
            ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://foo.com:8080/"

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            Include /etc/path/options-ssl-apache.conf
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/path/foo.com-0001/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/path/foo.com-0001/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What I had tried earlier was adding timeout=x and connectiontimeout=x behind ProxyPass but this didnt seem to help

Edit:
Since there is still no answer here is some more info, I will add a bounty once eligible.

As you can see in my VirtualHost file I am using Apache Reverse Proxy to enable SSL for my application

So my little nanohttpd server basically returns a very simplistic html page with a table and a row for each database entry. If the specific category has more than around 100 entries I will get the Proxy Error message.

At this point I am very certain that it has todo with something timeing out but I have went through so many posts and tried to add configs to mine and (yes I restarted Apache2 after every change) nothing worked so far.

Could it be something on my nanohttpd server that I am missing?
A simple Header or Cookie, I am sending none of those as of now.

If any required information is missing please let me know.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well funnily enough I figured it out and I feel horrible now..
The table data I was inserting included a dollar sign and apparently I did not think of escaping the replacement String

Comment: This answer makes no sense. What table data?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your input may have been malformed.